# Ionic 2 : Rest Api call

Tags: javascript, rest, angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm trying to get data from rest API using GET method but whenever I call function it gave me an error following are my code and error I'm getting:

**CODE**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class DataService {
public data:any
  constructor(public http: Http) {

  }

  load() {
  if (this.data) {

    return Promise.resolve(this.data);
  }


  return new Promise(resolve => {

this.http.get('http://localhost:65463/api/values')
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(data => {

        this.data = data;
        resolve(this.data);
      });
  });
}

}
```

Check in console and getting this error.
**ERROR**:

```
 ERROR Response {_body: XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent, status: 0, ok: false, statusText: "", headers: Headers…}
 main.js:1364
defaultErrorLogger main.js:1364
ErrorHandler.handleError main.js:1424
ngZone.onError.subscribe.next main.js:5053
schedulerFn main.js:4127
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub main.js:40952
SafeSubscriber.next main.js:40901
Subscriber._next main.js:40843
Subscriber.next main.js:40807
Subject.next main.js:59961
EventEmitter.emit main.js:4113
NgZone.triggerError main.js:4484
inner.inner.fork.onHandleError main.js:4445
t.handleError polyfills.js:3
n.runTask polyfills.js:3
invoke polyfills.js:3
GET http://localhost:65463/api/values  polyfills.js:2
XMLHttpRequest.n.responseBlob.r.function.o.(anonymous function).M.(anonymous function).(anonymous function) polyfills.js:2
e polyfills.js:3
t.scheduleTask polyfills.js:3
P.onScheduleTask polyfills.js:3
t.scheduleTask polyfills.js:3
n.scheduleTask polyfills.js:3
n.scheduleMacroTask polyfills.js:3
(anonymous function) polyfills.js:3
send
(anonymous function) main.js:47316
Observable._trySubscribe main.js:18744
Observable.subscribe main.js:18732
MapOperator.call main.js:100380
Observable.subscribe main.js:18729
(anonymous function) main.js:61156
t polyfills.js:3
DataService.load main.js:61150
ItemService main.js:40599
Object.defineProperty.get module.ngfactory.js:1
AppModuleInjector.getInternal module.ngfactory.js:1
NgModuleInjector.get main.js:3855
resolveDep main.js:11260
createClass main.js:11123
createDirectiveInstance main.js:10954
createViewNodes main.js:12303
createRootView main.js:12208
callWithDebugContext main.js:13339
debugCreateRootView main.js:12800
ComponentFactory_.create main.js:10145
ComponentFactoryBoundToModule.create main.js:3726
NavControllerBase._viewInit main.js:45155
NavControllerBase._nextTrns main.js:44967
NavControllerBase._queueTrns main.js:44924
NavControllerBase._setPages main.js:44851
(anonymous function) main.js:44822
t.invoke polyfills.js:3
inner.inner.fork.onInvoke main.js:4424
t.invoke polyfills.js:3
n.run polyfills.js:3
(anonymous function) polyfills.js:3
t.invokeTask polyfills.js:3
inner.inner.fork.onInvokeTask main.js:4415
t.invokeTask polyfills.js:3
n.runTask polyfills.js:3
a
```

I need helps guys! & need some good tutorial of angular 2 rest Api call

Comment: have you tried testing your api with a rest client?

Comment: @suraj yes I tried rest client and also I tried with browser it working fine there..

Comment: Maybe you are missing some headers you had set there..

Comment: A review of this example http://www.icoderslab.com/how-to-fetch-json-data-from-web-service-in-ionic-2-app-using-angular-2/ .Hope helps

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: @Aaryaans yes resolved